# factorizing Lombok annotation into another annotation like in @Data

Tags: lombok

Is there is a simple way to group your favorites lombok annotations into one annotations. Something like what @Data does for `@ToString`, `@EqualsAndHashCode`, `@Getter`, `@Setter`, and `@RequiredArgsConstructor` ?

I would like to assemble my own 'a la carte' annotation (let's call it ) `@MyData` that would package : `@NoArgsConstructor @EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id") @Getter`, `@Setter` and `@ToString`, but not `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

So I could just annotate all of my beans with `@MyData`, and not all the lombok annotations,
Is it achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like the idea, so I did some research. Seems this is not possible as of today.
But there is an ongoing discussion on [lombok-macro](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/project-lombok/oLqKQ8FVN2E) that leads in the direction and I also found a (didn't test) guide how to provide [custom lombok annotations](http://binkley.blogspot.de/2014/12/writing-your-own-lombok-annotation.html) which could do the trick if your own processor would reuse the existing processors.